# Rails: Remove Curly Braces in Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have the following code:

```
@temp = SalesOrder.where("status > ?", 0).ids
items = SalesOrderItem.where(sales_order_id: @temp).where.not(product_id: nil)

total = items.to_a.group_by(&:product_id).map do |product_id, quantity| 
  {:product_name => Product.find(product_id.to_i).name, 
   :quantity => quantity.sum { |q| q.quantity.to_f } }
end

@top_five = total.sort_by { |h| h[:quantity] }.reverse!
```

`@top_five` produces this array:

```
[{:product_name => "Six", :quantity => 1300.0},
 {:product_name => "Plastic Tumbler 620ml", :quantity => 1205.0},
 {:product_name => "Product Four", :quantit y=> 1110.0},
 {:product_name => "Product Five", :quantity => 510.0},
 {:product_name => "Fiber Optic Cable", :quantity => 200.0}]
```

I need it to be in this format

```
{"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}
```

or this

```
[["Football", 10], ["Basketball", 5]]
```

Comment: I can't see any similarities between your actual output and your expected output.

Comment: Its the curly and square brace format that I need fixed. Not the actual values inside. Problem solved by @AntonTkachov below

Comment: This just smells like a horribly convulted workaround instead of just setting up the correct associtions which would make this a trivial task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@temp = SalesOrder.where("status > ?", 0).ids
items = SalesOrderItem.where(sales_order_id: @temp).where.not(product_id: nil)
total = items.to_a.group_by(&:product_id).each_with_object({}) do |(product_id, quantity), total|
  total[Product.find(product_id.to_i).name] = quantity.map(&:quantity).map(&:to_f).sum
end
@top_five = total.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse!
```

Check this. It should work. If any errors, ping me, I will update it

PS: your code is not optimized at all. All of this could be done with single SQL query, but the logic is pretty hard to write this query without debugging

Comment: That solved it. Thanks for the tip, will research on recreating this in SQL.

Comment: You are abusing `map`, which is basically used to, well, _map_ the input. The correct version would be `total = blah.each_with_object({}) do |(id, q), total| ... end`.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, you are right about `.map`. Rewrote it to `each`. Haven't faced `each_with_object` before. It's defintetly very useful. What would be pros of using such method? It looks, that my code will still be the very same inside block, isn't it?

Comment: `. each_with_object` is a much cleaner way to create another object such as a hash without modifying an external object which is generally seen as hackish.

Comment: @max `s/hackish/phpish/` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa can you write down the whole `total = ` code? I can't figure out what you mean.

Comment: `total = items.to_a.group_by(&:product_id).each_with_object({}) { |(product_id,quantity), total| total[Product.find(product_id.to_i).name] = quantity.map(&:quantity).map(&:to_f).sum }`. In this particular case, the regular `map` is fine: `total = items.to_a.group_by(&:product_id).map { |product_id,quantity| [Product.find(product_id.to_i).name, quantity.map(&:quantity).map(&:to_f).sum] }.to_h`.

Comment: @mudasobwa thank you!

Comment: @mudasobwa Updated my answer with your advices. It was very useful info for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Always welcome.